# Selecting another column from a query with a different date filter

Tags: sql

I am working with some sales data and pulling the metrics for a particular week I am defining in the filter.
However, I want to add another column (first_sale_date) to my query. This will show the first time this asin/mp combo shows up in my table regardless of the date filter I am trying to pull the other metrics for.

Because I am already
filtering by date I don't know how to look back to all of the data in the table to find it's first appearance as it is before the week I am filtering for.

```
select date,
    ,asin
    ,marketplace
    ,SUM(ordered_product_sales) as OPS
    ,SUM(cogs) as cogs
    **,min(date) as first_sale_date**

from prod.sales

where date > '2023-01-01'

group by 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: @jarlh Im using Redshift on Datagrip

Answer (score 0):

you can use a correlated subquery for this

```
select year
    ,week
    ,asin
    ,marketplace
    ,SUM(ordered_product_sales) as OPS
    ,SUM(cogs) as cogs
    ,( SELECT MIN(date) FROM sales sal1 WHERe sal1.asin = sal.asin and sal1.marketplace = sal.marketplace) as first_sale_date

from prod.sales sal

where year = '2023' and week = '1'

group by 1,2,3,4
```